# Sklearn missing dll file

Tags: python, dll, scikit-learn

So I imported the sklearn module into my python script, which runs fine when executing from the terminal; but I wanted to turn it into an executable using PyInstaller, to which I used the following command: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile MainApp.py`. Now when I try to run my executable I get a missing dll file error; Note that this worked fine before I imported sklearn, which makes me think this is a problem with sklearn module.

I uninstalled and reinstalled said module but it did not work.

[image]

It is also interesting to note that the _MEI57882 folder does not exist in my my Temp folder

## Update

I've also run across instances of other people facing the same problem: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899, but it sounded like they were trying to fix the problem with the install, back in 2019. I have the latest sklearn module to date so I'm still running into the problem.

## Bigger Update

After talking with some contributes of scikit-sklearn, this error appears to be on the side of py-installer; not the module itself.